# Group by Query within Query

Tags: sql, group-by, firebird

I have a database running firebird.

I would like a SUM of the quanity of the items by itemloc and itemcode.
This data will be included in the final data with the individual serial numbers.

```
SELECT itemloc, 
       itemcode, 
       (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM item_data 
           WHERE itemcode = item_data.itemcode itemloc = item_data.itemloc 
                 AND usecode ='INV' 
           GROUP BY itemloc, itemcode ), 
       serialno 
FROM item_data  WHERE usecode ='INV'
```

^ This query gets the qty of each item with specific serialno but I want to ignore the serialno when I execute that part of the query.

```
SELECT itemloc, itemcode, SUM(qty) FROM item_data
   WHERE usecode ='INV' 
   GROUP BY itemloc, itemcode
```

^ This query gets the SUM that I want but cannot get the rest of the information I need.

tldr;
I want to make this work

```
SELECT itemloc, itemcode, 
   (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM item_data 
       WHERE usecode ='INV' AND itemcode = item_data.itemcode AND itemloc = item_data.itemloc 
       GROUP BY itemloc, itemcode), 
       serialno 
FROM item_data  WHERE usecode ='INV'
```

^ I get returns multiple rows in singleton select

Answer (score 1):

Does this resemble what you want?

```
SELECT itemloc
   ,itemcode 
   , serialno 
   , thesum
FROM item_data  join        
(SELECT itemloc, itemcode, SUM(qty) thesum 
FROM itemh 
WHERE usecode ='INV' 
GROUP BY itemloc, itemcode ) temp on item_data.itemloc = temp.itemloc
and item_data.itemcode = temp.itemcode

WHERE usecode ='INV'
```

Comment: it looks like the version of firebird we are running does not support  derived tables. Is there another way to do it?